# How to change timer for every single post in django

Tags: javascript, django

For every item in items I want to have a timer. I made a timer using javascript and I can show the timer for every single item. But when I want to show all the items in home page the timer is shown just for the last item. Is there any way to show the timer for all the items?

```
<div class="row m0 p0 justify-content-center">
  {% for item in items %}
  <div class="col-12 col-xs-6 col-md-4 card-item p0">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img class="rounded img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ item.image }}" />
      <div class="sold-img-item"></div>
      {% if item.sold == 1 %}
      <div class="sold">Sold
      <div class="sold-price"><span>{{item.highest_bid_offer}} €</span></div>
      </div>
      {% endif%}
    </div>
    <h5 class="no-flow capital "><b>{{item.title}}</b></h5>
    <div class="no-flow"><strong>Seller :</strong> {{item.seller}}</div>
    <div class="no-flow">
      <strong>Initial Price :</strong> <span>{{item.price}} €</span>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="auction_status" name="auction_status" value="{{ item.auction_status }}"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="end-time-fix" name="end-time-fix" value="{{item.auction_end_time}}"/>

    <div class="timer-small" id="timer-small">
      <div class="timer-small" id="days-small"></div>
      <div class="timer-small" id="hours-small"></div>
      <div class="timer-small" id="minutes-small"></div>
      <div class="timer-small" id="seconds-small"></div>
    </div>

    <a class="divLinkkk" href="{% url 'item_detail' item.id %}"></a>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I think you basic HTML mistake you are using id on HTML tag inside for loop. You should provide Javascript code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elorbratiing what @Mithlesh has pointed out

You need to change your time code like this

```
    <div class="timer-small">
      <div class="timer-small days-small"></div>
      <div class="timer-small hours-small"></div>
      <div class="timer-small minutes-small"></div>
      <div class="timer-small seconds-small"></div>
    </div>
```

Then fix your javascript to work with class instead of id.

Comment: In this way all the items shows the same timer while every item has its own timer

Comment: You can't use a single HTML ID for multiple elements.  Try adding dynamic ids/class and fix javascript to make separate timer for all items based on class/id identifier.